# Why this code gives a run-time error?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int in =0;
    for(int i =0 ; i<5 ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<5 ; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",in);
            if(in)
            {
                printf("%d",(abs(3-j)+abs(3-i)));
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Actually I tried this code to solve a problem, but it still gives a runtime error. 
 on this input sample

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

What does it give run-time error and how to fix this?, thanks.

Comment: `scanf("%d",in);` -> `scanf("%d",&in);` You forgot the `&` operator.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting._

Comment: Note well this general point:  myFunc(arg) cannot modify arg.

Answer (score 2):

the error here is : `scanf("%d",in);`

You can use `scanf()` for reading formatted input from `stdin`. 
You can check the syntax of `scanf()` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

The solution is adding the location of `in` variable with `&`

```
scanf("%d",&in);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int in =0;    
scanf("%d",in);
```

Syntax of scanf() is wrong. The argument should be a pointer.
It should be

```
int in =0;    
scanf("%d",&in);
```